# How can I expect maven to resolve dependencies required by the child jar?

Tags: maven

I have a parent project(has its own pom.xml) in which I import the child project as a jar with its own pom.xml.
In the parent pom.xml I have specified my child jar as a dependency - this gets resolved, but i want maven to resolve the dependencies required by my child jar.

My Use case to replicate :
When I include spring-web-mvc.jar the  transitive dependencies   are resolved automatically.
I have a similar requirement where I include my child.jar into a main framework project and expect the transitive dependencies to get resolved (Notw: the child.jar is not hosted it is packaged as jar and present on the local file system)

Current Structure:

Child Project:

> |----/src/main/java
>   |----/src/main/resources
>   |----child-pom.xml

```
>This child project will be a jar as dependency in the parent project
```

Parent Project

> |----/src/main/java
>   |----/src/main/resources
>   |----***/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/child.jar***
>   |---- parent-pom.xml

***The problem***:
When i create a war from parent project i want all the dependecy including transitive ones to show in WEB-INF lib.

Currently this is not happening.

Comment: Could you post your pom(s).xml please

Comment: Your dependencies should be there. Please post your poms.

Answer (score 0):

First when talking of parent/ child Maven projects normaly you have your"childs" specified as `modules` in a common parent project which itself is beeing packed with the packaging type `pom` rather than make them a dependency of the parent project.

When it comes to the dependencies of your "childs" or generally "dependencies of your dependencies" those are called transitive dependencies and are pretty well explained in the official documentation found here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

The resolving of those transitive dependencies is one of Mavens core strenghts and guaranteed by default unless they lead to conflicts that make the build fail.

Two things to help here are having a closer look into the enforcer plugin (http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) and the shader plugin (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) .... well and the official documentation of corse (reading the whole thing takes less than a day - then supports you further for specific topics whereas we gladly further support you too if you already have pom.xml files and you are stuck somewhere.

While the enforcer-plugin covers certain conflicts regarding different versions of the same artefacts the shader plugin will just pack everything you specified to a single jar for reverseengineering (its not the normal use case but i sometimes use it that way if i am not absolutly sure what ends in my final archives).

Also worth a look at is the dependency-plugin already available in the maven distributions - `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` will give you pretty detailed information on the resolved dependencies (and probably version conflicts).

Comment: Thanks user1902288 for that insight. I have updated the question

Comment: And do you get ClassNotFound-Exceptions at runtime or what is the actual problem? Because regardless if its 3th party or your own the dependency mechanism will resolve transitive dependencies (and may suppress certain ones because there is a version conflict - e.g. two of your direct dependencies depend on the same groupId:Artefact ("Artefact") but in a different Version. (Unless said child.jar itself doesn not result from a Maven project/ build - e.g. is no Maven Artefact)